# express.js why is root "/" path not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning express.js at the moment. Rigth now, my root "/" path is not working anymore. When I check localhost:3000/ nothing is displayed, just a blank page. I can't figure out why. When I use other pathes like e.g. "/hello" its working. Strangely I copied the code from an udemy lessons and its the exact same code. In the udemy lessons its working.

Where is my mistake? What did I do wrong?

I want localhost:3000/ to display my response "Hello"

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const hoganMiddleware = require('hogan-middleware');

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'mustache')
app.engine('mustache', hoganMiddleware.__express)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))


app.get('/hello' , (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Hello from hello');
})

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Hello')
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server is running on ' + 3000);
});
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code. Can you try changing your port or see if your browser is caching any page, and let me know if the issue is still there.

Comment: This exact code is works just fine returning `Hello` on GET `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Do you have an `index.html` in your `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` directory that does not contain anything "visible"?